# Overflow Exception. StringBuilder

Tags: c#, overflow

I am trying to convert a `StringBuilder` into an `Int64` but I get `Overflow Exception` and I cannot figure out why. The length of the string is not greater than the int. My current code is:

`+      $exception  {"Value was either too large or too small for an Int64."}   System.Exception {System.OverflowException}`

```
private static Int64 EightBit(string Data)
{
  StringBuilder Pile = new StringBuilder();
  char[] values = Data.ToCharArray();
  foreach (char letter in values)
   {
    // Get the integral value of the character. 
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
    // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form. 
    string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
    Pile.Append(Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(hexOutput, 16), 2));
   }
  return Convert.ToInt64(Pile.ToString()); //Error here
 }
```

Comment: Please provide minimal sample - you really need one line for this post like `Convert.ToInt64("8765432187654321")`... after you have such sample you may be able to answer yourself...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in this code? All those `Convert`s seems overcomplicated... What I see that you are trying to create `Int64` from binary representation stored in strng... Maybe you forgot to add `2` in `Convert.ToInt64(Pile.ToString(), 2)`

Comment: And not sure if you really want `int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);` as you are using ASCII value of character, so `0` becomes 48, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are converting the ASCII values of a string to their **binary** values ([`Convert.ToString(string, 2)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) converts to base 2, right?)

character -> ASCII value -> Hex string representation -> Int Value -> **Binary string representation of int value** -> try to parse that string in base 10.

For instance, if "Data" is "147483647", then "Pile" is "110001110100110111110100111000110011110110110100110111" which is clearly larger than 'long.MaxValue' *in base 10*.  By converting each character in a string to the binary representation of their ASCII values, you are creating a number string with far, far more digits than originally when you finally to to parse it base 10.

Just a quick step-through in the debugger should confirm the problem.